# Sync-backup directly to a USB flashdrive good or bad for its life?

Tags: usb, backup, sync, 7-zip

I've been using 7-Zip to sync-backup a huge folder from my hard drive (several hundred thousand files and folders) to a USB flash drive, like so

```
7z u F:\backup.7z -uq0 C:\HugeFolder\* -r -ssw -ms=off
```

Everything works great.

But now I am wondering whether this puts too much stress on the USB drive in terms of reads and writes, and whether I should **1)** copy `backup.7z` to local harddrive first, **2)** sync-backup it as above **3)** finally copy it back on the USB? Would doing it like that increase the life of my USB, or is the impact of doing it "live" negligible?

Thank you.

Comment: A number of USB Flash Drives I have used over the years have simply expired at a most inopportune time. I never use them for backup and my clients do not use them for backup.  High quality, brand name USB Hard Drives are much better for backups but watch carefully that these remain working well

Comment: You'd also need to consider how much of the data actually changes from one backup to the next.  If it's a very small fraction of the whole, then the current approach seems best, as those few reads and writes would be relatively efficient.  But if there are many updates, then the second approach of reading and writing the entire archive might be better (and possibly faster, if that's a concern).

Comment: @RayButterworth Very good point. I'd say the amount of change every time is ~10%. Do you think that's an amount I can go with for current practice? Also, does 7-zip process things locally and only makes read/write calls for changes? Thanks.